# Two Dimensional Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I will get the input from the user like this - "99211,99212,99213_1,99214,99215_3" and I store it in a string as

```
string cpt = "99211,99212,99213_1,99214,99215_3";
cptarray = cpt.Split(',');
```

I got the output as

```
cptarray[0] = "99211"
cptarray[1] = "99212"
cptarray[2] = "99213_1"
cptarray[3] = "99214"
cptarray[4] = "99215_3"
```

But I would like the output to be:

```
cptarray[0][0] = "99211",""
cptarray[1][0] = "99212",""
cptarray[2][0] = "99213","1"
cptarray[3][0] = "99214",""
cptarray[4][0] = "99215","3"
```

If I need to get the output like above then can I use the 2D array, is it the correct approach?

Comment: Maybe you could use a Dictionary<long, int> or Dictionary<string, string>

Comment: What you show is not a 2D array, but a jagged array (an array of arrays).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the syntax provided:

```
 cptarray[0][0]
 ...
 cptarray[4][0]
```

you want a *jagged* array, not *2D* one; you can construct this array with a help of *Linq*:

```
 var cptarray = cpt
   .Split(',')
   .Select(number => number.Split('_'))
   .Select(items => items.Length == 1 ? new string[] {items[0], ""} : items)
   .ToArray();
```

Test

```
string test = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, cptarray
  .Select((line, index) => string.Format("cptarray[{0}] = {1}", 
     index,
     string.Join(", ", line.Select(item => "\"" + item + "\"")))));

Console.Write(test);
```

Output

```
 cptarray[0] = "99211", ""
 cptarray[1] = "99212", ""
 cptarray[2] = "99213", "1"
 cptarray[3] = "99214", ""
 cptarray[4] = "99215", "3"
```

Comment: this line shows syntax error - string test = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, cptarray
  .Select((line, index) => 
    $"cptarray[{index}] = {string.Join(", ", line.Select(item => "\"" + item + "\""))}"));

Comment: @Aruna: do you use C# *6.0*? `$"..."` is a *string interpolation* which appears in C# 6.0

Comment: @Aruna: I've changed *string interpolation* for *string formatting* in the `test` (see my edit)